How do I pass the variable I defined in the procedure to another procedure in delphi?
Now I got two buttonclicks, the first one is what I use to open a wav file and apply some distortion to it. I used opendialog during this process, now I want to play the sound file that I use opendialog to open in the first procedure. How do I do that? Because the variable(for the file that I open by opendialog) defined in first procedure cannot be passed to another procedure.
I would be grateful if anyone could solve this issue for me.
I wish I could get this issue solved, I could be able to play the file that I selected in the previous procedure.
Here are my current code for two procedures, and I tried to use opendialog again in second procedure, but the result is unexpected.
    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    type
        TWavheader = record
          idRIFF: array[0..3] of Ansichar;
          Chunksize: longint;
          idWave: array[0..3] of Ansichar;
          idFormat: array[0..3] of Ansichar;
          Subchunksieze: longint;
          Audiofmt: smallint;
          Numchan: smallint;
          Samplerate: longint;
          Byterate: longint;
          Allign: smallint;
          Bps: smallint;
        end;
   TDataheader = record
     idData: array[0..3] of Ansichar;
     datasize: longint;
   end;

var
  myFile: TFilestream;
  Waveheader: TWavheader;
  Dataheader: TDataheader;
  datain, dataout: array of SmallInt;
  datafactorin: single;
  datafactorout: smallint;
  Sample: single;
  i: integer;
  numofsamp, frequency: integer;
  channel, bitpersamp: Smallint;
  Inputfile: string;
  Outputfile: string;
  threshold1: single;
  threshold2: single;

begin
        Opendialog1.execute();
        Inputfile := Opendialog1.filename;
        threshold1 := StrToFloat(Upperthreshold.Text);
        threshold2 := StrToFloat(Lowerthreshold.Text);
        myFile := TFileStream.Create(inputfile, fmOpenRead);
        myFile.readbuffer(Waveheader, sizeof(TWavheader));
        if (Waveheader.idRIFF <> 'RIFF') or (Waveheader.idWave <> 'WAVE') then
         raise Exception.Create('Selected file is not a valid WAV file.');
        bitpersamp := Waveheader.Bps;
        channel := Waveheader.Numchan;
        frequency := Waveheader.Samplerate;
        if (bitpersamp = 0) or (channel = 0) then
        raise Exception.Create('Invalid WAV header: bitspersamp or channel is zero.');
        myFile.readbuffer(Dataheader, sizeof(TDataheader));
        numofsamp := Dataheader.datasize div (channel * (bitpersamp div 8));
        Setlength(datain, numofsamp);
        SetLength(dataout, numofsamp);
        myFile.Readbuffer(datain[0], Dataheader.datasize);
        if numofsamp > 0 then
        for i := 0 to numofsamp -1 do
          begin
            Sample := datain[i];
            datafactorin := Sample/32767;
            if datafactorin > threshold1 then datafactorin := threshold1;
            if datafactorin < threshold2 then datafactorin := threshold2;
            datafactorout := round(datafactorin * 32767);
            dataout[i] := datafactorout;
          end;
        Dataheader.datasize := Length(dataout) * SizeOf(SmallInt);

        Outputfile := 'D:\output.wav';
         if numofsamp > 0 then
         myFile := TFileStream.Create(Outputfile, fmCreate);
         myFile.Writebuffer(Waveheader, sizeof(TWavheader));
         myFile.Writebuffer(Dataheader, sizeof(TDataheader));
         myFile.Writebuffer(dataout[0], Dataheader.datasize);
         myFile.free;





end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 opendialog1.execute();
 sndPlaySound(PChar(opendialog1.filename), SND_NODEFAULT);

end;

end.


You have only shown us the procedure, but your class TForm1 has class-member variables that are available to all methods. That's where you put shared data.

Your main problem is that you have crammed all your type definitions and data handling variables into the first button's OnClick event handler. As a result, the types and data are not visible from the second button's event handler. You should also consider to move all data handling (data structures, file reading, sample modification and file writing etc. to a second unit. Keep all event handlers in Unit1 as short as possible (e.g. just as calls to functions and procedures in the second unit).

I change some local variable to global variable now, but I still can't access the file that I selected during the button1click. I only want my button2 to have function of play the audiofile, so I cannot move my datahandling to button2. I wish my button1(I named it open) to read the selected file and modify it only when I click it,, therefore, I only can write file handling within the button1click procudure. What should I do to access to the file that I selected in button1 when I click button2?

I did not tell you to move your data handling to Button2. Please reread my previous comment carefully. If you don't want to do it correctly, maybe it would help if you move variable OutputFile: string; to your forms public section, and play that from your Button2 click.

Thanks, I will try to do in second unit and see how.

You have opendialog1. It defined for form as I guess. OpenDialog has FileName property that's you need. Just delete OpenDioalog1.Execute in the second procedure. Better way in your case is define variable for file name in form.
Advice: don't place program logic in event handler. Never

I tried to delete the opendialog1.execute, but when I run the program, there is no response when I click button2. It's not playing the file that I selected.

@ChenYuxuan, before performing opendialog1.execute() check whether opendialog1.filename contains valid filename. If yes, just use it without performingopendialog1.execute() Maybe, the better way would be putting some path edit control: before valid filename is specified, all dependent controls should be disabled.

In my procedure button2, there is no file name contained in opendialog1.filename, I think it's because opendialog is only executed in first procudure, and the valid filenamed it contains is not passed to the second procedure

@ChenYuxuan Without knowing your Code it is realy hard to give good advice. please provide a minimal reproducible sample. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@fisi-pjm The issue is that when I try to access the file that selected in buttonclick1 in another procedure, the opendialog1.filename is empty, so I can't continue other works.

You may create a function
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    OpenDialog1: TOpenDialog;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FWavFileName: string;
    function ChooseFile(bForceDialog: Boolean=False): Boolean;
  public

  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if ( not ChooseFile() ) then Exit;
  // your code here
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if ( not ChooseFile() ) then Exit;
  // your code here
end;

function TForm1.ChooseFile(bForceDialog: Boolean): Boolean;
begin
  Result := FileExists(FWavFileName);
  if ( bForceDialog or not Result ) then begin
     Result := OpenDialog1.Execute() and FileExists(OpenDialog1.FileName);
     if ( Result ) then
       FWavFileName := OpenDialog1.FileName;
  end;
end;

end.


Sorry for just seeing tour replyu. Thanks, I will try it.
